# How i can make counter for place with thymleaf to my table?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

How i can make loop for this table counter place, like place 1,2,3,4 or i must send it from java too?

```
<tr th:each="player : ${getStatsResponsePvp}">
                                        <td th:with="place=${player.counter + 1}"th:text="${place}"></td>
                                        <td th:text="${player.CharName}"></td>
                                        <td th:text="${player.Level}"></td>
                                        <td th:text="${player.ClassName}"></td>
                                        <td th:text="${player.PvpKills}"></td>
                                        <td th:text="${player.PkKills}"></td>
                                        <td th:text="${player.OnlineText()}"></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <span th:if="${player.online} == 0"
                                                  class="label label-danger">Offline</span>
                                            <span th:if="${player.online} == 1"
                                                  class="label label-primary">Online</span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make use of [Thymeleaf's iteration status](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status). Try something like:

```
<tr th:each="player,status = ${getStatsResponsePvp}">
```

You can then use `${status.count}` to enumerate which player you are up to.